# Cypress setCookie not working with Firefox in a Docker container

Tags: docker, firefox, cookies, cypress

I'm using Cypress 7.5.0 and I run my E2E tests in a Docker container based on cypress/browsers:node12.16.1-chrome80-ff73.

The tests have been running on Chrome for a while now.
When trying to execute them on Firefox, I've got the following error :

```
CypressError: `cy.setCookie()` had an unexpected error setting the requested cookie in Firefox.
```

When I run the tests locally (outside the Docker container) and use the version of Firefox installed on my computer (Ubuntu 18.04), the same code works fine.

In order to authenticate in my application, I retrieve the following cookies :

```
[
  {
    name: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    value: '7a8b8c79-796a-401a-a45e-1dec4b8bc3c3',
    domain: 'frontend',
    path: '/',
    expires: -1,
    size: 46,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    session: true
  },
  {
    name: 'JSESSIONID',
    value: 'B99C6DD2D423680393046B5775A60B1C',
    domain: 'frontend',
    path: '/',
    expires: 1627566358.621716,
    size: 42,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    session: false
  }
]
```

and then I set them using :

```
cy.setCookie(cookie.name);
```

I've tried overriding the cookie details using different combination like :

```
cy.setCookie(cookie.name, cookie.value, {
  domain: cookie.domain,
  expiry: cookie.expires,
  httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
  path: cookie.path,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'Lax',
});
```

but nothing works.

I can't get my head around why it works when run locally and fails when run in a Docker container. Any ideas?

Thank you.